# Login Test with Jenkins and Symfony2

Tags: database, testing, symfony, jenkins

I configured jenkins in order to automating the tests for my project. The unit tests work well. Now I want to do some test with my database. For example the login test: enter the username, the password (submit the form). Do you have an idea of how to do this? Thank you.

Here is the test I want to do but it does not work:
Get the home page, test if the link FAQ is present two times, click on the first FAQ link, test if the link RMK is present, click on login, test if forgot password link is present, enter my username and my password submit the form, get the profile page, test if My Profile link is present.

```
    <?php

namespace RMK\SocialBundle\Tests\FunctionalTests\Controller\Website;

use RMK\SocialBundle\Controller\Website;
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\RedirectController;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Tests\TestCase;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerNameParser;

class HomeControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{    
    public function testViewFAQ(){
        $client = static::createClient();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/home');
        $this->assertEquals(2, $crawler->filter('a:contains("FAQ")')->count());
        $this->assertEquals(2, $crawler->filter('a:contains("FAQ")')->count());
        $faqlink = $crawler->filter('a:contains("FAQ")')->eq(0)->link();
        $crawler = $client->click($faqlink);
        $this->assertEquals(1, $crawler->filter('a:contains("RMK")')->count());

        $loginLink = $crawler->filter('a:contains("Login")')->eq(0)->link();
        $crawler = $client->click($loginLink);
        $this->assertEquals(1, $crawler->filter('a:contains("Forgot Password?")')->count());


        $form = $crawler->selectButton('_submit')->form();
        $form['_username'] = 'username';
        $form['_password'] = 'test';

        $crawler = $client->submit($form);
        $crawler = $client->followRedirect();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/profile');
        $this->assertEquals(1, $crawler->filter('a:contains("My Profile")')->count());
    }
}
?>
```

The last assert failed by saying: Failed asserting that 0 matches expected 1. When I put  var_dump(print_r($client->getResponse()->getContent())); just before this last assert I got this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=/home" />

        <title>Redirecting to /home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="/home">/home</a>.
    </body>
</html>bool(true)
```

I am sure I am missed something but I don't know what. Do you have an idea? Thx.
P.S: I am on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: try adding another `$client->followRedirect();` before the request to profile and see if it's working.

Comment: I tried to add another $client->followRedirect(); before my client request but it does not work, here is the error: LogicException: The request was not redirected. In my test I don't check in the database if the user exists, perhaps the problem come from that? I tried a LOT of things but I can't figure it out. I found some tutorials but everytime they don't speak about the database (I am wondering how do their tests can pass).

Comment: Did you try `$client->followRedirects(true);` in the beginning? You should remove all `$client->followRedirect();` when you use this. If it works, your problem is redirection!

Comment: I tried but the error is still here -> Failed asserting that 0 matches expected 1 (for my last assertTrue)...